# GoToTags - NFC Tag Reader ACR122U

Tags: nfc, rfid, iso-15693

I have an ACR122U reader that reads many tags but not the ICODE SLIX SL2S2002 tag. Why might that be the case? I have tried the tag on a mobile device and it is recognised.

Answer (score 3):

The ICODE SLIX SL2S2002 uses the ISO/IEC 15693 standard. Your reader (ACR 122U) contains an NFC chip (PN532) that only supports ISO/IEC 14443 (+ MIFARE Classic) and ISO/IEC 18092 (+ Felica). Hence, your reader simply does not support the protocol required to communicate with that type of tag.